# ASP.NET MVC3 database manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Right now, I have a simple web application that displays the entries of a database. One of the fields that is visible in the database is a bool?, which is true, false, or neither. Everything in the database originally should have the bool? set to neither.

Here's what I want to get working: when a user edits an entry in the table by selecting either true or false for the bool? field, I want to be able to run some C# code (that I have already written) and have that entry deleted from the database. This means that the next time that the database is loaded, once again all the entries will have neither true nor false selected in the bool? field.

Does someone know how I can do this simply? (I know very little about querying databases or creating web apps in general.)

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: "MVC3" + "CRUD" should give you what you want. Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277576/AJAX-based-CRUD-tables-using-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jTa

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE BOOLFIELD = 1 ???

Comment: @ErikPhilips: It would be more polite to at least ask him to post some code first. He has stated that there is a "simple web application" in place.

Comment: Hello Everyone -- Thanks for all the quick input, but I actually got this worked out for myself after a really lucky observation (I noticed something on a screenshot somewhere that was meant to describe a completely unrelated problem). I'll create an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was less about how to delete the items and more about how to pick out from the database those chosen to be deleted.

I found that this does the trick:

```
var toBeRemoved = from m in db.Issues
                           where m.Remove.HasValue && m.Remove
                           select m;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you say "true, false, or neither", the neither means null in the database, so, without seeing your code, I believe you could change the `SELECT` that retrieves the rows for the view to display, to have a `WHERE *field* IS NULL` in it. If this doesn't help, please post us some control, view, and model code.